# How to reproduce a oblique launch (like Angry Birds) using js?

Tags: physics, game-physics

I need reproduce an oblique launch of some object, like a man throwing a stone up to the air. Actually I have no idea of how can I begin the code.

Comment: I'd suggest learning some physics to start

Answer (score 0):

You must use "free fall" formula: y = y0 + v0*t -(g*(t^2))/2

In this case, v0 is initial velocity. Supouse 10.  And, g is gravity accelerator constant (in real world ~= 9,8 m/s^2). Supouse you use 10 to make more easy.

You will call a Interval thats make the new position. Your increment should be t.

I.e

```
function height_formula(t){
    var h;
    var h0 = 0;
    var v0 = 10;
    var g = -10;
    return h0+(v0*t)+(g*t*t/2);
}
```

Then, you should call this function in interval.

```
t = 0;
function apply_formula(){
    var obj = document.getElementById('id');
    obj.style.position = 'absolute';
    obj.style.marginBottom = height_formula(t);
    ++t;
}
interval = setInterval(apply_formula,500);
```

Note: y in physics has oposite direction in computer science. I used marginBottom instead marginTop  because this.

Answer (score 0):

Angry birds uses a physics engine. You can try and implement only the free fall. This would be a pretty basic implementation. Just have a velocity and push it down by a constant. However it may be easier to implement position, velocity, acceleration vectors. You can then use euler integration to get the new velocity and position every frame.